# How i can use distance Matrix api to get direction between two places (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, google-maps-sdk-ios, google-distancematrix-api

How I can use distance Matrix API to get direction between two places , I search a lot of in internet but I can't find effective tutorial and detail

Can anybody help me to find a good tutorial ??

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationDistance meters = [firstLocation distanceFromLocation:secondLocation];

Use corelocation framwork.the two locations are of types cllocation coordinate

Comment: i try "var distance = firstLocation!.distanceFromLocation(secondLocation!)" in swift but it dosn't work

Comment: show your full code.Print the location first or put a break point to make sure your getting location.